# Why does ejabberd wants to create erlang cookie in /home? #crash: permission issues

Tags: build, configuration, ejabberd, user-permissions

in the documentation they said to configure as user ejabberd i.e. but do they mean a system user or a normal user. I don't know why but if I do so it wants to create an erlang.cookie sometimes in $HOME/.erlang.cookie and sometimes in $HOME/ejabberd/.erlang.cookie and I can't figure out why. As I configured the build to use my username instead everything worked fine.

(the steps were tried out with system user and regular user ejabberd without a home directory created before step 3)

```
step 1: ./configure  --enable-user=ejabberd --disable-stun --enable-sqlite
step 2: make
step 3: sudo make install
step 4: copy the service file to systemd/system directory and starting the service
step 5: receiving the error that the erlang.cookie can't be created because of no
        permisson for /home/ or because /home/ejabberd does not exist
```

Pointing to the documentation the cookie should be created in /var/lib/ejabberd/.erlang.cookie [ [Docs](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/installation/#system-install) ]

Would be very nice if you can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in the documentation they said to configure as user ejabberd i.e. but do they mean a system user or a normal user.

A normal user! ejabberd doesn't need any privilege or root access to work (only port 80 for ACME certificate renewal, but a port forward is enought).

> Pointing to the documentation the cookie should be created in /var/lib/ejabberd/.erlang.cookie [ Docs ]

In old times, HOME was set to SPOOLDIR (Docs still say that), but this was changed in
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/40ef406ec7412f7a81240d1e7567953ca11ffe43#diff-58efbd248a3f69bc63a62926359bbcb142a2c4b239bd5166e1b9ad5528c47270L108

So, Docs and ejabberdctl.template are wrong in this part, and need an update: the user running ejabberd needs a HOME, because the cookie is stored there.

> As I configured the build to use my username instead everything worked fine.

Right, because your personal account have a HOME where erlang can create the cookie file.

This works for me:

```
❯ sudo adduser ejacount3
S'està afegint l'usuari «ejacount3»…
S'està afegint el grup nou ejacount3 (1006)…
S'està afegint el nou usuari ejacount3 (1005) amb grup ejacount3…
S'està creant el directori personal «/home/ejacount3»…
...

❯ ./autogen.sh; ./configure --enable-user=ejacount3
allow this system user to start ejabberd: ejacount3
...

❯ make
...

❯ sudo make install
...

❯ sudo su ejacount3 ejabberdctl live
2021-10-06 11:23:53.400422+02:00 [info] ejabberd 21.07.62 is started in the node ejabberd@localhost in 5.35s
...
```

It's also possible to use systemd:

```
❯ vim ejabberd.service
User=ejacount3
Group=ejacount3

❯ sudo cp ejabberd.service /etc/systemd/system/

❯ sudo systemctl daemon-reload 

❯ sudo systemctl enable ejabberd.service

❯ sudo systemctl start ejabberd         

❯ sudo systemctl status ejabberd
● ejabberd.service - XMPP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ejabberd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-10-06 11:30:31 CEST; 1min 21s ago
...

❯ sudo su ejacount3 ejabberdctl status
The node ejabberd@localhost is started with status: started
ejabberd 21.07.62 is running in that node
```

Comment: thank you! i need to reconfigure that, I used it now with a system account and a manually created home directory. why they don't update the documentations? -.-

Comment: The documentation has been updated now.